# document.getElementById("st").click(); not working

Tags: javascript

I want to click a button automatically on every page refresh.But when i have the window.location.reload function the button click is not happening.I am really confused on this one.What to do to get a button clicked automatically on page refresh?

```
    window.setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.reload();
    repeat();

    }, 2000);

    function repeat(){

    document.getElementById("st").click();

    }
```

Comment: why not put it in a condtion if the the window.location.reaload() then do the click !! sure it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    window.setTimeout(function () { repeat();  
window.location.reload();  
}, 2000);
```

Call repeat before reload function.

Comment: Akshay Thanks for the help but unfortunately it is not working

Comment: Have you defined onclick function for the button?

Answer (score 1):

This is working!

```js
document.getElementById("st").onclick = function() {
  alert('Clicked');
};

window.setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.reload();
  repeat();
}, 2000);

function repeat() {
  document.getElementById("st").click();
}
```

```html
<div id="st">Div</div>
```